# Installing xsane without gimp?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, xsane

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gimp gimp-data libamd2.3.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.3.1 libccolamd2.8.0
  libcholmod2.1.2 libgegl-0.2-0 libgimp2.0 liblcms1 libmng2 libumfpack5.6.2
  xsane-common
Suggested packages:
  gimp-help-en gimp-help gimp-data-extras liblcms-utils hylafax-client
  mgetty-fax gv gocr
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gimp gimp-data libamd2.3.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.3.1 libccolamd2.8.0
  libcholmod2.1.2 libgegl-0.2-0 libgimp2.0 liblcms1 libmng2 libumfpack5.6.2
  xsane xsane-common
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 44.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Why does it want to install `gimp` as a dependency? So far, I've always been able to use `xsane` standalone? I certainly doubt `gimp` is required for `xsane` to run - so how can I install `xsane` alone without `gimp`?

EDIT: The weird thing is that here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xsane , `gimp` is listed with blue as "suggests", and shouldn't "suggestions" be ignored by default?

Comment: gimp is only a suggested dependency.

Comment: Thanks @muru - why does it then automatically want to install itself, if it's only suggested? Or is that how apt-get works?

Comment: @muru gimp is not a suggested. It is a hard dependency. `gimp-help`, etc are suggested.

Comment: Yes, suggested dependencies are skipped by default. Did you enable it in the past?

Comment: @Pilot6 not in my 14.04: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15629529/

Comment: @muru - that's what I thought, that is why this behavior surprised me. I don't recally manually enabling it, but maybe something I've installed did. Anyways, good to have it confirmed how it should go, probably some setting changed somewhere - and by the way, your duplicate helped - `--no-install-recommends` did install without `gimp` - many thanks! Feel free to close...